# How to rotate UISegmentedControl and increase the size to fit any amount of text

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I've been trying to use UISegmentedControl as a multiple-choice selection tool. I thought that if I could rotate it 90 degrees (as well as the text inside) and expand the cells, it would be a very fluid tool. However no matter what I try it keeps giving me variations of this[image: broken UISegmentedControl]

By the way, this is inside a UICollectionView. Here is my code for the UICollectionViewCell

```
class customCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var questionDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var viewForSegment: UIView!
var segment: CustomSegmentedControl!

func heightForView(text:String, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}

func loadQuestions(choices: [String], pointIndex: [Int]) {
    segment = CustomSegmentedControl(items: choices)
    segment.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI / 2.0));
    for view in segment.subviews {
        for sv in view.subviews {
            if sv.isKindOfClass(UILabel){
                let subview: UILabel = sv as! UILabel
                subview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI / 2.0))
                subview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview,
                    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
                    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
                    toItem: nil,
                    attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
                    multiplier:1,
                    constant: heightForView(subview.text!, width: self.viewForSegment.frame.width)))
                subview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview,
                    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
                    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
                    toItem: nil,
                    attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
                    multiplier:1,
                    constant: self.viewForSegment.frame.width))
            }
        }
    }
    segment.pointIndex = pointIndex
    /*
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: segment, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeftMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: segment, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: segment, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.RightMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: segment, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: questionDescriptionLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
    segment.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: questionLabel.x, y: ), size: segment.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize))
    */

    segment.bounds.size = segment.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize)
    viewForSegment.addSubview(segment)
    viewForSegment.frame.size = viewForSegment.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)` to rotate the control 90 degrees,
and `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2)` on each segment to rotate it back.
You'll then need to calculate the resulting frame/bounds.

```
// rotate view
self.transform = newValue ? CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2)) : CGAffineTransformIdentity

let padding : CGFloat = 8
let maxSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat.max, height: CGFloat.max)
var size : CGSize
var maxHeight : CGFloat = 0
var totalWidth : CGFloat = 0

// reverse rotate segment content
for segment in subviews {
    for contentView in segment.subviews {
        size = contentView.sizeThatFits(maxSize)
        maxHeight = max(maxHeight, newValue ? size.width : size.height)
        totalWidth += (newValue ? size.height : size.width) + padding
        contentView.transform = newValue ? CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-CGFloat(M_PI_2)) : CGAffineTransformIdentity
    }
}

// adjust size
bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: totalWidth + padding, height: maxHeight + 2*padding)
```

Feel free to use my `UISegmentedControl.vertical` extension:
https://gist.github.com/yonat/18261fd04cd11a3e9959835509b312c2

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by doing like this

```
segmentControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)
```